# snowflake placeholder format to use with the golang driver

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I haven't been able to locate the placeholder format to use with the golang driver for snowflake. The docs here https://godoc.org/github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake currently do not state anything about it and their examples https://github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake/tree/81a8e973392a6d20381ab3797de63ba584f8d0d6/cmd do not use it also. Should I be using "?" or "%s"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go Driver for Snowflake [implements](https://github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake/blob/master/statement.go#L5-L35) [golang database/sql](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) [interfaces](http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html#parameter-placeholder-syntax).

Assuming that by ***placeholder format*** you are talking about [SQL statement bind variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), you can use the [standard variable syntax supported by Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html#syntax): Either `?` (*unnamed, positional*), or `:name` (*named*):

An example of positional-style:

```golang
db.ExecContext(ctx, `
    delete from Invoice
    where
        TimeCreated < ?
        and TimeCreated >= ?;`,
    endTime,
    startTime,
)
```

An example of named-style:

```golang
db.ExecContext(ctx, `
    delete from Invoice
    where
        TimeCreated < :end
        and TimeCreated >= :start;`,
    sql.Named("start", startTime),
    sql.Named("end", endTime),
)
```

The [gosnowflake](https://github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake) module docs [carry an indirect reference](https://godoc.org/github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake#hdr-Binding_Time_Type) to this but since they implement the `database/sql` interfaces, they implicitly support sending regular and named args alongside a statement to the Snowflake service.